# How does negative regex lookaround works when put in if clause?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am trying to use regex capturing groups and lookarounds to match all instances of a specific word from a sequence, but only if it is not surrounded by & and ; symbols(i.e. I don't want to capture `word` from`&word;`, but I do from `&word` or `word;`).

I wrote a regex that I thought would satisfy my needs, but it doesn't - it seems that negative lookaround I put in if clause makes only first group not-matched instead of whole match.

`(&[^;&]*)?(amp)(?(1)(?!;))`

When used on this string: `>amp; &amp; amp &amp; &amp<` I expected that only first, third and fifth amps would be matched, due to negative lookaround, but unexpectedly all of them are matched with only &'s are excluded when followed by `;`.

https://regex101.com/r/ilAAVb/1

Am I making some obvious mistake here, or lookarounds in if clause work only for group that clause is checking?

Edit: Corrected what I need to extract from a sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `(*FAIL)(*SKIP)` verbs, try to match `&word;`, if found, discard the match then try to match `amp`

```
&.+?;(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|amp
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/ilAAVb/2)

Comment: Thanks for your input, that is exactly what I was looking for! I had to change ```&.+?;``` to ```&[^&]*;```, to also capture ```&word``` that might appear in the middle of sentence.

Comment: @Gynju: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant, but this works:

```
(&\b\w+\b(?!;)|(?<!&)\b\w+\b(?!;)|(?<!&)\b\w+\b;)
```

`(&\b\w+\b(?!;)` for `&` at start but no `;` at end

`(?<!&)\b\w+\b(?!;)` for no `&` at start and no `;` at end

`(?<!&)\b\w+\b;)` for no `&` at start but `;` at end

Comment: I wonder if I should edit my original post, because I now see a mistake in there - in fragments like ```&word``` and ```word;``` I need to capture only the ```word``` part. & and ; should be omitted from capturing group.

Comment: @Gynju Yes, please edit and state what you need: explanation  of a pattern (then your question is a duplicate), or a solution to a real problem. Explain the real problem please.

Comment: If you don't want to capure & and ; here you go: (?:&(\b\w+\b(?!;))|(?<!&)(\b\w+\b)(?!;)|((?<!&)\b\w+\b);).

Comment: @Vincent Much closer to what I can actually use :). Is there maybe a way to capture all words into single group? I tried working with named groups but they need unique names.